# VBA code to show message box popup if the formula in the target column exceeds a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code on this site for a particular cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("A1") > 0.5 Then
    MsgBox "Discount too high"
End If
End Sub
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to make this work for an entire column rather than one particular cell?

Comment: A Change event won't work for a formula, only for static values. You'd need to use the Calculate event - how would you want to handle multiple values exceeding your threshold? Multiple message boxes, or only one?

Comment: Look at using a loop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Ideally I would like it to look at only the row I'm actively changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your event code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rr As Range, r As Range
    Set rr = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    For Each r In rr
        If r.Value > 0.5 Then
            MsgBox "Discount too high"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

if you want to restrict the message to a single row, then remove the first sub and replace it with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    rt = Target.Row
    If Range("A" & rt) > 0.5 Then
        MsgBox "Discount too high"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does work to a degree but I have cells in the range where the discount is too high and it needs to stay that way so everytime I amend one of the cells in row that affects the range i'm selecting I end with about 20 pop up boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is the wrong way of doing thing in Excel :).

Can I suggest the following:
1. Add Conditional Formatting to cells depending on the values e.g. > 0.5
2. Add in the cell next to this cell a simple IF formula that signal the error.

Using events will suppress undo operations